# Relative Paths for the animate Package

Tags: animate

I would like to use relative images with the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package. I have tried both using the `\graphicspath` as shown below and typing in the relative path. Either way the code fails. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work (since `animate` is built on the `graphicx` package)?  Any suggestions for a work around? I would really like to be able to keep my images in a separate directory

```
    \graphicspath{{"../../../Project Work/Shot Database/Data/CFD/15/"}}

    %This line works
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{v-top-0002}

    %This line doesn't
    \animategraphics[loop,autoplay,width=6.5in]{12}{v-top-}{0001}{0008}
```

Comment: As soon as I have some time left, I will look into it.

Comment: It works if you don't use directory names with spaces. Replace spaces with underscores or use CamelCase names. In general, spaces in directory and file names are a bad idea. Don't understand why people cannot resist using them.

Comment: BTW, Your `\includegraphics` line will only work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AlexG Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `animate` makes use of `graphicx`' `\graphicspath` in order to locate graphics files in other directories than the standard ones.

Your example would perfectly work if you didn't use spaces in your directory names. Spaces should always be avoided. CamelCase names or underscores are good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\graphicspath{{../../../Project Work/Shot Database/Data/CFD/15/}}` without `""`.

And remember put this line before `\begin{document}`.